# calculations on specific rows in table of database using php

Tags: php, mysql, calculation

i'm working on a php project that manages teachers in school. but i'm stuck with a problem, i have two tables in my database, first one T1 has on row, second T2 has multiple rows, but they have the same columns number. in a third table T3 i need to fill a column with the total of
 (cell1 of T1*cell1 of T2) + (cell2 of T1*cell2 of T2)+ (cell3 of T1*cell3 of T2)....to the last column
i just couldn't find the right way to do this

[image]

this is the part that shows the tables from my db

```html
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$bdd="test";
$cnx=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if(!$cnx)
 echo"connexion echouee"."</br>";
else
 echo"connexion reussie"."</br>";

if (mysql_select_db($bdd))
 echo"base de donnees trouvee"."</br>";
else
 echo"base de donnees introuvable"."</br>";

  $req1="SELECT * FROM `table1`";
  $res1=mysql_query("$req1");
  // printing table rows
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_row($res1))
  {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach($row1 as $cell1)
          echo "<td>|$cell1|</td>";
      echo "</tr>";  echo"</br>";
  }
echo "_____</br>";
  $req2="SELECT * FROM `table2`";
  $res2=mysql_query("$req2");
  // printing table rows
  while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($res2))
  {
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach($row2 as $cell2)
          echo "<td>|$cell2|</td>";
      echo "</tr>";echo"</br>";
      
  }
?>
```

Comment: share your code so far?

Comment: So do you intend to achieve this through PHP or MySQL?

Comment: i intend to use php , but i need mysql to get the content of the tables

Comment: It's worth noting that the `mysql_*` family of functions no longer exist in any supported version of PHP. You should probably be using `PDO` or at a minimum `mysqli`. Any tutorial using `mysql_connect` is horribly out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse second table and calculate total with nested loop:

```php
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table1`");
$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table2`");

$row1 = mysql_fetch_row($res1);
$row = 0;

// for each row of second table
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($res2)) {
    $row++;
    $total = 0;

    // for each column of first table's row
    foreach ($row1 as $index => $table1RowValue) {
        // get value of same column in the second table's row
        $table2RowValue = $row2[$index];

        // calculate aggregated value
        $total += $table1RowValue * $table2RowValue;
    }

    // print result
    echo "Line $row: $total</br>";  
}
```

Comment: Your'e welcome. Also, consider this comment from other SO user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610616/calculations-on-specific-rows-in-table-of-database-using-php/55613228#comment97936131_55610616

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is *guaranteed* that table1 will return 1 row, here is a suggestion:

- Instead of using a `while` loop to fetch the contents, just fetch the row, so the contents of table1 are in `$row1`
- Change `foreach($row2 as $cell2)` to a `foreach($row2 as $key=>$value)` format. This way you will have the index of the corresponding element in `$row1`
- Inside the `foreach($row2 as $key=>$value)` loop, use an accumulator to calculate "Column I". E.G. `$tot += $value * $row1[$key]`
- "echo" the accumulater column before the `</tr>`

You also probably want to add an empty `<td>` in the `$row1` loop to make sure that all the rows have the same number of columns.